# Why are proofs based on the 2 classical logics?

Tags: logic

Mathematics recognizes that there are logics different from the propositional logic and the predicate logic. I have studied a few of them myself.

Then... why are all proofs in math textbooks based on propositional and predicate logics only?

I mean, why do these proofs assume that it's either $A$ or not $A$?
Or... why do they assume that the negation of "for all $X$, we have that $P(x)$ holds true" is "there exists an $X$ such that not $P(x)$"?

Isn't this a flaw in the credibility of math itself (or say of all these texts)?

I guess it's not but I am not sure why.

Comment: If you think that it is wrong to use classical logics for all proofs, do you mean that there exist some proofs that better do not use classical logic?

Comment: i'm also curious about the alternative. ie what is the alternative to
$¬(\forall x \Rightarrow p(x)) = \exists x \nRightarrow p(x)$

Comment: I think this is an interesting question. Looking forward to the replies.

Comment: In constructive logic, the negation of “for all $x$, we have that $P(x)$ holds true” is not “there exists an $x$ such that not $P(x)$”.  Instead, it is the stronger statement “Here is a particular $c$ for which we can disprove $P(c)$”.  (This is of course sufficient in classical logic as well.) Constructive logic is widely used in some contexts.

Comment: interesting, ive not yet come across that line of logic yet though in all honesty it seems fairly equiviliant to a slight change of the above. statement. but this raises a fair rational for why we may find propositional and predicate logic being so prevelant.

to a man with a hammer, everything looks like a nail.

perhaps propositional and predicate logic is just people's first point of protocol and they just happen to work.

Comment: See [Intuitionistic Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/) and [Constructive Mathematics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-constructive/).

Comment: i'm unconvinced from what i've read so far. it seems to me (and by all means please correct me) that trying to verify mathematical uncertainities on computational output is (although very scientific) not very mathematical and adds a layer of uncertainity. Using the above arguement i dont see how

$\exists c$ for which we can disprove $P(c)$ as the negation of $\forall x \Rightarrow P(X)$

Comment: Does this question basically amount to "How do we justify the laws of logic (in particular, the law of the excluded middle)?" If not, how does it differ? (I'm not criticizing, I just want to clarify what's being asked here.)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I did not say it's wrong. I just wanted to understand why the proofs are based on these 2 particular logics.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I didn't mean exactly how we justify it. In fact it cannot be justified, I think, if we happen to be in some other logical system e.g. a 3-valued logic.

Comment: i aplogise for my ignorance. can you give an example of 3-valued logic?

Comment: @Vaas Sure. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic